# I accidentally created 2 UK visa applications on Gov.UK site. One involves no payment, the other one has payment involved

Tags: visas, uk

I made one application online but realized I input wrong information in No.2 Application tab and I was not able to edit this information after hitting save button on No.4 Declaration tab just before making any payments on No.5 Pay (IIHS payment)tab. The online application did not provide me any options to withdraw this application because I didn't make any payments yet, and there was no reference number provided.

I made another online application with the correct information and the same email used in the first application and payments were made and I am ready to use this application to go to the visa center for documentation submitting. However, the 10 week wait for the first non-payed application to expire is after visiting the visa center and waiting for approval.

Is it safe for me to think that the first application because nothing was payed for is not considered a multiple application, and I can allow it to expire in 10 weeks without worries that it will affect the second application visa process? or should I contact the UK office for them to remove it before I visit the visa center?

Answer (score 4):

For UK Visa, if you didn't pay, you didn't apply. That's all. No need to worry about it.

It shows at the end of the application that if you made a mistake beyond that point, you have to submit another application.